# Flutter build failed (DateTime issue)

Tags: flutter

I try to build app using this command :

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get && flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

I get this error a lot of time :

Bad state: Unexpected diagnostics:
/Users/xxxx/Documents/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/core/date_time.dart:919:61 - Expected an identifier.
/Users/xxxx/Documents/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/core/date_time.dart:919:64 - Expected an identifier.
/Users/xxxx/Documents/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/core/date_time.dart:919:64 - Expected to find '('.

When I'm looking to date_time.dart I can see this file in error.
[image]

Flutter doctor :

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.11, on macOS 12.5.1 21G83 darwin-x64, locale fr-FR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
• No issues found!
```

In my pubspec.yaml :

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"
```

Maybe the Dart version is not the good one ?

Comment: Create a small example of this error, try to remove parts of the code that don't influence the error. And finally, post all the code here so it can be reproduced.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution ?